# How many CPU cores Geoserver support or handle

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-manager

I am using Geoserver to serve 10000 users concurrently. I need to know, how many CPU cores Geoserver can handle. How many CPU cores we can add in Geoserver?

Comment: All of them if you let it, the cores are controlled by the JVM and the OS